# ¿Como mando un dato de un input type file a JavaScript y de ahí mandarlo a php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Explico estoy trabajando con `HTML`, `JS` y `PHP`. Ya he trabajado con estas herramientas de programación con anterioridad. Pero en lo referido a imágenes, realmente nunca he trabajado con dichas imágenes. Si bien, puedo decir que existe el método tradicional el cual seria, hacer un formulario con **enctype="multipart/form-data"**, la realidad es que estoy trabajando también con `javascript`, el mismo es mi mayor duda de como se mandan los archivos, en este caso imágenes, y de ahí se pasan a `PHP`. Ya que noto que si es algo diferente.

**HTML**

```
<form id="formal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="id">ID de la empresa:</label><br />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="xid" name="xid" placeholder="ID de la empresa" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Nombre de la empresa</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="xnombre" name="xnombre" placeholder="Nombre de la empresa"/>
        </div>



     <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Imagen de la empresa</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="ximg" name="xnombre"/>
        </div>

        <div class="from-group">
        <span id="res"></span><br />
        <input type="button" id="botonaimg" value="Agregar" class="form-control btn-primary"/>
        </div>

        <div class="from-group">
        <span id="resupd"></span><br />
        <input type="button" id="botoncimg" value="Modificar" class="form-control btn-success"/>
        </div>     
   </form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  $('document').ready(function() //Jequery es capaz de identificar si la pagina 
    {
        $('#botonaimg').click(function() //se cargo en su totalidad
            {

                if($('#xnombre').val()=="")
                {
                    alert("Introduce el nombre de la empresa");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    var imnombre = $('#xnombre').val();
                }

                if($('#ximg').val()=="")
                {
                    alert("Introduce imagen");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    var imagen = $('#ximg').val();
                }

                jQuery.post("/..php/imagenes/agregar.php",
                {
                    imnombre:nombre,
                    imagen:imagen
                }, function(data, textStatus)
                {
                    if(data== 1)
                    {
                        $('#resp').html("Error Conexion");
                        $('#resp').css('color','red');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(data == 2)
                        {
                            $('#resp').html("Datos agregador");
                            $('#resp').css('color','green');

                            $('#desarrolladoras').bootgrid('reload');
                            borrar();                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(data == 3)
                            {
                                $('#resp').html("Error, estas intentando introducir una desarrolladora que ya existe o introdujo un caracter no valido.");
                                $('#resp').css('color','red');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(data == 4)
                                {
                                    $('#resp').html("Error de metodo");
                                    $('#resp').css('color','red');
                                }
                            }
                        }    
                    }    
                });


            }); 
    });
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

//Esto es para validar que los parametros  vengan con GET

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {
        $nombre         = $_['nombre'];
        $imagen         = $_['imagen'];

    //una pequeña vaalidacion por si las dudas

        if($nombre == '' || $imagen == '')
        {
            echo 1;
        }
        else
        {
            require_once('../conexion.php');
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `bd`.`imagenes`(`nombre`,`imagen`,`estado`) VALUES ($nombre,$imagen,1);";

            //Tring to insert the value to db
            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
                echo '2';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '3';
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
    else
    {
        echo '4';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace poco hice una mini-libreria para realizar el proceso de subir archivos por ajax.

[reader.js](https://github.com/spardo6/reader.js) (solo referencia, no es necesario implementar)

Básicamente lo único que debe cambiar en el código del Ajax es el uso de la función `FormData` con la cual debe serializar el formulario y enviarlo como la data del ajax, el proceso del lado del servidor es el mismo que con cualquier imagen o archivo.

```
var form = document.querySelector("#formal");
var formData = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
  url: "/..php/imagenes/agregar.php",
  type: "POST", // Para jQuery < 1.9
  method: "POST",
  data: formData,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log("Response: ", response);
    // Código en caso de éxito
  },
  error: function(exception) {
    console.error("Ocurrió un error", exception);
    // Código en caso de error
  }
});
```

> Es **importante** cambiar la función `$.post()` por `$.ajax()` ya que se necesitan configurar algunas propiedades como el `processData`.

[Documentación FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData)

Comment: Oh ya gracias, ahora mi problema, ¿Seria es en donde coloca las validaciones? Ya que quiero validar tanto desde el servidor (que ahí ya valide) como en frontend.

Comment: El código lo debería mantener tal cual esta en este momento, solo cambie la función `$.post()` por el código de la respuesta además de agregar la lógica para el callback del `success` y el `error`.

Comment: Ah ya veo, no tome en cuenta eso ya me funciono, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tu tienes un **input** supongamos:

```
<input id="upload-input" type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple="multiple">
```

ahora con `javascript`, capturas cuando exista un cambio en el osea cuando aya cargado un fichero para mandarlo por una petición al server, quedándote así:

```
$('#upload-input').on('change', function () {

  var files = $(this).get(0).files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    // 
    // crear un objeto FormData que se enviará como la carga de datos en la
    // solicitud AJAX 
    var formData = new FormData();
    // recorrer todos los archivos seleccionados y agregarlos al objeto formData
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];
      //agregue los archivos al objeto formData para la carga de datos
      formData.append('uploads[]', file, file.name);
    }
    //Peticion ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: '/ruta_server', 
      type: 'POST', 
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      xhr: function () {
        // creas una XMLHttpRequest
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (evt) {
          if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            // calcular el % del proceso de la subida al servidor
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100); // con esta variable podrías por ejemplo llenar una barra de progreso

            if (percentComplete === 100) {
              //cuando aya llegado al 100% , puedes realizar la operación que desees
            }
          }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
      }
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log('upload successful!\n' + data); // cuando se completa la petición el servidor podria enviar success, 
    });
  }
});
```